Setting an AWS MQTT Trigger with the ASW CDK for .Net
I've made an AWS based application, which has a Lambda that is triggered by an MQTT message. I've manually created a rule to trigger the lambda. But I need to codify this rule into the CDK project. Otherwise it must be manually recreated on every deploy. I can't figure out the objects that I need to initiate from the CDK to accomplish the same thing. Can someone point me in the right direction. This is how the rule for the trigger shows in the AWS console.
        IoTRule1:
          Type: IoTRule
          Properties:
            Sql: >-
              SELECT *, topic() as topic, sourceip() as source from
              "info/update"

How would I express this same thing in the .Net version of the CDK?
Thanks.
